Git Showing Same Line Removed and Added after Merging Master into Feature Branch
After I merged from master, there were a few conflicts which I resolved, I am seeing various files having the same line deleted and added back in. I am not sure where this is coming from or how to resolve it.
I tried to do a git squash on all the commits but no luck.

